# socket.io with redis adapter on express.js: how get all sockets session into room?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I want retrive the session of all sockets into room.

I have shared the `express-session` with the session of socket.io with `express-socket.io-session`.

My serever:

```
import * as sharedsession from 'express-socket.io-session';
import * as session from 'express-session';
import * as connectRedis from 'connect-redis';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as SocketIO from 'socket.io';
import * as redisSocket from 'socket.io-redis';

// redis optinon
const redisOption = { port: 'XXX' };


// express.js
const app = express();

// create the redis store for the express session
const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);
const expressSession = session({
      name: 'SESSIONID',
      store: new RedisStore(redisOption),
      secret: 'as54f6a65sf4fa',
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: { secure: true }
});
// set the session into express
app.use(expressSession);


// socket.io
const io = SocketIO(httpServer, {path: '/api/socket.io', origins: '*:*'});
// se the adapter for socket io
io.adapter(redisSocket(redisOption));
// share the express session with socket io
io.use(sharedsession(expressSession, {autoSave: true}));

// just for test, join all socket into a room 'foo'
io.on('connection', (client) => {
    client.join('foo');
});


// start the express server
app.listen(3000);
```

My attemp to retrive users session into room:

```
io.in('foo').clients((err, clients) => {
    for (let i = 0, e = clients.length; i < e; i++) {
        const client = clients[i]; // socket id
        // HOW GET THE SOCKET SESSION?
    }
});
```

i have also tried

```
// this works only for the current instance, don't return all sockets into the redis adapter
const sockets = io.sockets.adapter.rooms['foo'].sockets;
```